# Rails 4 css BG assets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that I have launched to heroku. In my development environment my CSS background is loading fine. However, I cannot figure out why its not loading in my production environment.

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background: url('letters.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

I read a heroku article about adding to my application.rb file:

```
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

However it said that I don't need to do this if I have this gem:

```
     gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Is my syntax wrong or do I need to add some piece of code elsewhere?

Comment: Are there any error on heroku? You can see any errors by using Chrome with Javascript console.

Comment: I checked heroku logs, it says:       ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/letters.jpg"):

Comment: Confirming with Rails version (3 or 4), you should see heroku doc(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline). Maybe you should `reke assets:precompile` on local, `git add` and `git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `url(asset-path('letter.jpg'))` instead of `url('letters.jpg')`
And for it to work in heroku, you have to precompile your assets locally and push in heroku, to do that run `$rake assets:precompile` and then push the generated assets file to heroku.

Comment: I tried url(asset_path('letters.jpg')) but this doesn't load on my production or my development environment.

Comment: @JoséToy ok try this `url(asset-path('letters.jpg'))` and also along with this, you have to  run `$rake assets:precompile` and commit and push the assets file generated in the public folder into the heroku.

Comment: I still get the ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/letters.jpg") error. It seems lie that syntax isn't working in my bootstrap css file either. The rest of my assets are loading fine elsewhere on my site though.

Comment: the file should be `.scss`, if its `.css`, it might cause problem, try changing the file extension. also instead of `"/assets/letters.jpg"`, the url generated should include a long MD5 like this `"/assets/letters-675anh519346ce297bb09ddd96afb953.jpg"`

Comment: This worked. However (due to my lack of css syntax) I had to remove "no-repeat center center fixed;" and adjust the views link to stylesheets. This is fine for now, but just for future reference do you know how I would fix this issue if I wanted to keep the center fixed portion of my code? Thanks for the help!